# No ItemSelected call in my UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview

So I'm trying out Xamarin Forms, and I made a control that has a renderer that outputs a UICollectionView. The collection view in question was ported from an Objective C version. In the Objective C version, I implemented `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and when I clicked on the item that method was called. But in the Xamarin version, this does not seem to be the case and the `ItemSelected` method is not called. I've tried using both the `Delegate` and `WeakDelegate` versions to no avail. I made sure `AllowsSelection` is true.

I tried adding a UIButton to the cell, and was able to get a log entry from its TouchUpInside handler, so I don't think it's a matter of another view on top stealing the touches. Pans and such work. And in Simulator I had it highlight the drawn layers and didn't notice anything fishy.

Anyone have any ideas of stuff to try? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did eventually fix this. What was happening is that Xamarin.Forms adds a gesture recognizer to the root of the page which cancels touches in the page. This works well in general, but does not work well in the case of `UICollectionView`s where it interferes with the `UICollectionView` calling `ItemSelected`.

What I ended up doing was to create this custom renderer:

```
public class IosTapFixPageRenderer : PageRenderer {
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        foreach (var g in View.GestureRecognizers) {
            g.CancelsTouchesInView = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I assigned this as the renderer for problem pages containing `UICollectionView`s using the usual attribute method:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CalendarPage), typeof(IosTapFixPageRenderer))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can help you, but i get the same problem using the GridView control of the Xamarin.Forms.Labs.

I see that in  delegate, the method "ItemSelected" is not called, but is call the "ItemHighlighted" method. So I used this to make the GridView selectitem works.

I hope this can be helpfull. :)

Comment: Unfortunately ItemHighlighted doesn't work either. I've flagged it as a bug in Xamarin's Bugzilla database at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21177 .

Comment: If you want take a look, my solution was added to the GridView control of Xamarin.Froms.Labs. Maybe reading the full code can help you find the solution: https://github.com/XForms/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/236

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you have assigned the `UICollectionViewSource` object to `ColelctionView.Source` and NOT `ColelctionView.DataSource` by mistake